# Angular 4: Call public method between two components of equal hierarchy

Tags: angular

I have two components called in my app. I've searched here and online and only found conclusive examples about components with parent and child relationships.

The app.component.html follows as:

```
<component1></component1>
<div class="container">
     <component2></component2>
</div>
```

My (sanitized) component1 uses a function that calls a function in component2 that gets from a service and sets a handful of variables within the scope of component2, that are tied to data bindings in the HTML of component2

```
//COMPONENT 1
private handler: component2Component;
ExecuteFunction(){
    console.log("Called");
    this.handler.GetLatest();
}
```

The function being called in component 2 follows as:

```
//COMPONENT2
public GetLatest(): Subscription{
    console.log("GetLatest Called");
    return this._component2Service.GetLatestFromService()
    .subscribe(outputData => this.outputData = outputData, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error)
}
```

However, I get the following error: Cannot read property GetLatest of undefined at the location of component1 button that executes ExecuteFunction().

Do I need to instantiate an instance of Component2 first? I'm under heavy data sanitation requirements unfortunately.

**I would just like to know how I can call the component2 GetLatest() method from a button within component1. Thanks!**

Comment: If you are using same data at 2 different components then you can use @injectable. https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection Also you can edit and view it from different components

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of a component is ONLY to provide the properties and methods needed by the view associated with the component. Hence no component should need to call methods in another component.

Components may need to pass data between themselves, and you can do that with route parameters, route resolvers, or using techniques defined with parent/child components (@Input and @Output).

If you have more general/shared functionality, that code should be in a service. Then any of your components can access the methods of the service.

One option for solving this is to use the repository pattern. Build a service who's purpose is to retrieve and expose the data. This *could* be your current data service. Or you could build a second service that retrieves the data from the data service and exposes it for use by either component.

Another option that would work if these components were not actually part of app.component's template would be to use a route resolver. That would allow you to retrieve the data before navigating to the route that displays the template containing these two components. Both components could then access the data retrieved by the route resolver.

I have an example of a route resolver here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-routing

Comment: So building on that then - the reason why I made two components is because they both have fairly large HTML templates and serve largely different functional purposes. Being that component1 is largely for data input and component2 is for the output and heavy formatting of the data returned. Would my solution now be to just implement all of it within 1 component now? And call the service from the one large component?

Comment: Great thank you, I'll look into the solutions you've given! Thanks for your pluralsight tutorials as well!